# What does session mean in the function for Alexa skills?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

When I read the code to make an Alexa skill in python, I am confused by session. Can you tell me what session means in the function? (session_attribute, or session.get('attributes', {}))
Thank you

Comment: Cite Python in the question and tag C++. Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the session object to save data, for example, save the state of the conversation.